# How to create Hyperlink for SharePoint List Form

Tags: javascript, html, list, sharepoint, hyperlink

I am pretty new to coding and have been tasked to update a SharePoint Form at my work and the task seems simple, but I am unable to do it.

I need to make the word "Fishbone Diagram" in the current code below into a hyperlink that will show up on the SharePoint list form.

Here is the current code:

```
$('input[id^="Primary_x0020_Root_x0020_Cause_x_"').parent().parent().parent().before("<tr> <td class='primaryrootcause' colspan='2'>Primary Root Causes - List root causes (use the Fishbone Diagram or 5 Whys tool to help you determine the root cause)</td></br></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know from experience that dealing with SharePoint form customizations like this is hardly ideal but if you're intent on keeping this approach, you only need to escape the quote characters in the JS above to create nested HTML elements.

The full solution would be like this:

```
$('input[id^="Primary_x0020_Root_x0020_Cause_x_"').parent().parent().parent().before("<tr> <td class='primaryrootcause' colspan='2'><a href=\'https://www.google.com/search?q=fishbone+diagram\' target=\'_blank\'>Primary Root Causes</a> - List root causes (use the Fishbone Diagram or 5 Whys tool to help you determine the root cause)</td></br></tr>");
```

Specifically, the original part of the string:

`(use the Fishbone Diagram...`

becomes...

`(use the <a href=\'https://www.google.com/search?q=fishbone+diagram\' target=\'_blank\'>Fishbone Diagram</a>`

Note the use of `\'` as an escaped quote character for wrapping the `href` and `target` attribute values of the `<a>` tag.

I've also assembled a working CodePen here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpBZbJ

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Sure thing SWynne - I've also tweaked the example to show the hyperlink on the 'Fishbone Diagram' text specifically

Comment: Great! I appreciate the help. Really saved my behind.

Comment: No problem - and if it indeed helped, please mark the answer as 'Accepted'